# Settings not saving bools or ushorts

Tags: c#, winforms

My ints are saving and loading just fine, but none of my ushorts or bools are. My names are exact and their types are matching up. I tried to break the line to see why, but it doesn't trigger.

Yes I am calling

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Save button Click

```
Properties.Settings.Default["Enable"] = (bool)Enable;
Properties.Settings.Default["tkey1"] = (ushort)Keybinds.tkey;
```

Load button Click

```
Enable = Convert.ToBoolean(Properties.Settings.Default["Enable"]);
Keybinds.tkey= (ushort)Properties.Settings.Default["tkey1"];
```

Comment: Have you called `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` at some point? What is the scope of those Settings? Why are casting?

Comment: This sounds like a stupid question even to me since you say ints are saving, but are you calling Save() on properties? Because you don't show that you are.

Comment: I am calling the save. That's why my ints are saving and loading just fine. The casting is just because. I wasn't sure if it was necessary so I just kept them.

Comment: In which section are defined these settings? ApplicationSettings or UserSettings?

Comment: It's defined as UserSettings

Comment: And how do you check if they are saved or not? Did you check if reading back the values they are updated?

Comment: Well, I can see the checkbox. I save it as checked, but when I uncheck and load it, it doesn't change.


I made a label and when I click load with the code ```label4.Text = Properties.Settings.Default["Enable"].ToString();``` It goes to true, but the checkbox itself doesn't change.

Comment: Why don't you add a `PropertyBinding` to bind the `Checked` property of the CheckBox (and other properties as well), then add `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` in the `OnFormClosing()` override? You have everything automatic this way and you don't need other Fields and stuff around. -- If you don't know about this feature, a description of the procedure [here](https://stackoverflow.com./a/61160815/7444103)

Comment: The PropertyBinding worked perfectly for the bool, but I'm still lost on what to do for the ushort though :S

Comment: There's nothing special you need to do. If the Setting is an `ushort` and you set an `ushort` value (without casting, so you get an exception if it's not), then that's all. As mentioned, add `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` in the `OnFormClosing()` override. Make sure (double check) what this Setting is, remove it and add it again, see that it's in the User Scope, nothing else in your code reset it (or uses `Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();` or `Reset()`), etc.

Comment: The value IS set as ushort. That's why I'm confused on why it's not saving.

Comment: If I remove the ushort casting, it gives me an error saying Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'ushort'.

Comment: Then you have your answer: `Keybinds.tkey` is of Type `object` and not `ushort`. Possibly `null`. Convert it (if that's actually possible) to an `ushort` value instead of casting it.